# mysql select something if exists

Tags: mysql, join, exists

I got two tables:

```
Article
-article_id
-name
-price

Attributes
-attribute_id
-article_id
-name
-value
```

I want to select everything from every article and if an attribute with the name "color" exists, I want this value selected too.
So that an example result looks like:

```
Result_table
article_id;  name;    price;  value
         1;  thing1;    24$;
         2;  thing2;    20$;  red
         3;  thing3;    10$;  blue
         4;  thing4;    19$;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a LEFT JOIN. And the condition `name = 'color'` must be in the ON clause. This way you will keep articles that don't have the 'color' attribute.

```
SELECT art.*, attr.value
FROM Article art
LEFT JOIN Attributes attr
  ON  attr.article_id = art.article_id
  AND attr.name = 'color'
```

Comment: Thanks. That totally did it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT article_id, price, value FROM Article 
LEFT JOIN Attributes 
ON Article.article_id = Attributes.article_id
```

The `LEFT JOIN` keyword returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The result is `NULL` from the right side if there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `LEFT JOIN` with `IF`, e.g.:

```
SELECT a.article_id, a.name a.price, IF(att.name = 'color', att.value, '') AS value
FROM article a 
    LEFT JOIN attributes att ON a.article_id = att.article_id;
```